# How to test applications developed for Win8 metro interface in other PC

Tags: visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, export, windows-8.1

As simple as that, I developed an application for TwinUI interface (Win 8.1) using Visual Studio 2012 and now I'd like to test my application in other device, how to export and execute my app in other PC, tablet, notebook???

thanks in advance

---

**EDIT** visual response as well (spanish)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNmONrM8yL4&list=PL42BA69E8D50586A1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a package and then put all the files created and run the PowerShell script created on the testing machine:

[Sharing an App Package Locally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh975356.aspx)